# How to programmatically check a view to test if it has any results?

Tags: views

What's the most lightweight way to test if a view has any results in it or not? I have a system which creates links to various views, but if the view has no results I want the link to be greyed out. I can only think to load the whole view and execute it, but hopefully there is an easier solution?

I should also note that these views contain contextual filters, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your options:

- Trim down the "view" to return only 1 row of possible results.
- Attack the problem from the other side. Use a `Rule` or a `Hook` to track the condition of your event (eg, "is there new content of type X") in a site `variable` and check that value instead of your View.

... etc ...

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have found so far:

```
<?php
$view = views_get_view_result($name, $display, $args);
$result = count($view);
if ($result) {
//do something here
}
?>
```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/446798#comment-6439726